# How to write makefile for bulk processing?

Tags: make

I have some files in a folder `source`. I want to process them using program `program` and output them into folder `target` just by typing

```
$ make
```

How should I write a makefile for this?

Directory tree:

```
/ 
   Makefile 
   program
   /source
      foo.x
      bar.x
      spam.x
   /target
      foo.y
      bar.y
      spam.y
```

Comment: [This might be helpful](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc_Rules)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard source/*)
TARGETS := $(patsubst source/%.x, target/%.y, $(SOURCES))

all: $(TARGETS)

target/%.y: source/%.x
    program -i $< -o $@
```

Comment: works like a charm! :)